# find names that match either of two patters

Tags: r, regex, string, character, tidyverse

Is is possible to find the names in a vector that contain either `id` OR `group` Or both in the example below?

I have used `grepl()` without success.

```
a = c("c-id" = 2, "g_idgroups" = 3, "z+i" = 4)


grepl(c("id", "group"), names(a)) # return name of elements that contain either `id` OR `group` OR both
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use  :

```
pattern <- c("id", "group")
grep(paste0(pattern, collapse = '|'), names(a), value = TRUE)
#[1] "c-id"      "g_igroups"
```

With `grepl` you can get logical value

```
grepl(paste0(pattern, collapse = '|'), names(a))
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

---

A `stringr` solution :

```
stringr::str_subset(names(a), paste0(pattern, collapse = '|'))
#[1] "c-id"      "g_igroups"
```

Comment: can I add another patter like `"id|group|grp"`? Also can we make the pattern not case-sensitive? `"id|group|grp"` = `"iD|Group|Grp"` = `"ID|GRoup|GRp"` . . .?

Comment: Yes, you can add as many patterns as you want using `|`. To make it case insensitive you can set `ignore.case = TRUE`

Answer (score 0):

Using str_detect:

```
> names(a)[str_detect(names(a), 'id|groups')]
[1] "c-id"       "g_idgroups"
> names(a)
[1] "c-id"       "g_idgroups" "z+i"       
>
```